# Getting a callback when asyncronous tasks are completed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm creating a basic migration class for my app.

```
// commands/migrate.js
const Question = require('../models/Question');

class Migrate
{
    constructor() {

    }

    run() {
        console.log("Deleting entries...");

        Question.remove({}, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            console.log("Entries deleted. Seeding...");

            for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
                new Question({
                    id: i,
                    title: "Who are you?",
                    answers: [
                        "Answer 1",
                        "Answer 2",
                        "Answer 3",
                        "Answer 4"
                    ],
                    correctAnswer: 0
                }).save((err, entry) => {

                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log(entry.id + "seeded!");
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = () => {
    return new Migrate()
}
```

My `server.js` looks like this.

```
if (typeof process.argv[2] !== "undefined") {
    switch (process.argv[2]) {
        case "migrate":
            require('./commands/' + process.argv[2] + '.js')().run()
            break;

        default:
            throw new Error("Invalid command.");
    }

    return;
}
```

`Question` model relies on `Mongoose`. Right now I get the following console log.

```
Deleting entries...
Entries deleted. Seeding...
0 seeded!
...
20 seeded!
```

However, I want to add one more line at the bottom when task is completed, so it looks like this.

```
Deleting entries...
Entries deleted. Seeding...
0 seeded!
...
20 seeded!
Command successful. Process exiting. // process.exit(0)
```

Is there any way to do this? Should I throw a callback when last query successfully completes or something?

Comment: Uh, yeah.  You have to keep track of when your last async operation completes and call a callback.  That typically involves using some sort of counter or switching over to use promises to manage your async operations.  You seem to already know that.  Why didn't you just try that?

Answer (score 0):

You could put an if statement after the line that has

`console.log(entry.id + "seeded!");`

`if (entry.id === 20) console.log('Command successful. Process exiting.');`